# Counting number of clicks

Tags: unity-game-engine, counter

I want to use Unity to calculate the number of clicks on the page as well as the number of clicks on a coin that appears every few seconds. Can you tell me how I can get the number of clicks on the page?

each time I want the number of clicks on the coins and the page to be calculated separately.

Comment: increment the value of a variable every time a click is detected

Comment: Thanks for your answer
But each time I want the number of clicks on the coins and the page to be calculated separately.
in This way that you told , if I click on the image, the number of clicks for the page will also be calculated.

Comment: so, you know the number of clicks on an image, and you know the number of clicks on the page .... it appears that your question is about simple arithmetic, not about programming

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear what you have in mind about `coin`. Its a UI element or a `GameObejct`.

I suppose its an object with `RigidBody` and `Collider`:

```
public class HitDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public static int allCounter = 0;
    public static int hitCounter = 0;
        
    
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            allCounter++;
            if (IsHit())
            {
                hitCounter++;
            }
            
            Debug.Log($"All: {allCounter} & hit: {hitCounter}");
        }
    }

    private bool IsHit()
    {
        return Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.current.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);
    }   

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.is there another way that i will be able to number of clicks on screen an image (without raycast)??